# #include <random> started to throw a lot of errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio, random, c++17, visual-studio-2019

Was writing some code, then tried to launch it, and got about 500 errors.

After some time, I created a new project and started removing pieces of code I wrote to detect what causes the error.

I ended up with this:

```
#include <random>
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

And to my surprise, it didn't solve the errors!
Still have about 50 errors, and when I try to compile the project I get this:

```
Build started ...
1> ------ Build started: project: test, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1> test.cpp
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\random (374.5): error C2760: syntax error: unexpected token "id"; "expression" is required
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\random (463): message: a reference to an instance of the class function template "std :: linear_congruential_engine <_Uint, _Ax, _Cx, _Mx> "
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\random (374,5): error C2187: syntax error: unexpected element "id" here
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\random (374.5): error C2062: "unsigned int" type is not required
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\random (374,1): error C2238: unexpected tokens before ";"
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\random (469.5): error C2760: syntax error: unexpected token "id"; "expression" is required
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\random (556): message: a reference to an instance of the class function template "std :: linear_congruential <_Uint, _Ax, _Cx, _Mx> "
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\random (469.5): error C2187: syntax error: unexpected element "id" here
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\random (469.5): error C2062: "unsigned int" type is not required
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\random (469,1): error C2238: unexpected tokens before ";"
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\random (865.5): error C2760: syntax error: unexpected token "id"; "expression" is required
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\random (925): message: a reference to an instance of the class function template "std :: subtract_with_carry_engine <_Ty, _Wx, _Sx, _Rx> "
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\random (865,5): error C2187: syntax error: unexpected element "id" here
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\random (865.5): error C2062: "unsigned int" type is not required
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\random (865,1): error C2238: unexpected tokens before ";"
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\random (1185.5): error C2760: syntax error: unexpected token "id"; "expression" is required
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\random (1261): message: a reference to an instance of the class function template "std :: mersenne_twister_engine <_Ty, _Wx, _Nx, _Mx, _Rx, _Px, _Ux, _Dx, _Sx, _Bx, _Tx, _Cx, _Lx, _Fx> "
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\random (1185,5): error C2187: syntax error: unexpected element "id" here
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\random (1185.5): error C2062: "unsigned int" type is not required
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\random (1185,1): error C2238: unexpected tokens before ";"
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\random (1410.5): error C2760: syntax error: unexpected token "id"; "expression" is required
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\random (1544): message: a reference to an instance of the class function template "std :: independent_bits_engine <_Engine, _Wx, _UIntType> "
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\random (1410,5): error C2187: syntax error: unexpected element "id" here
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\random (1410,5): error C2062: "unsigned int" type is not required
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\random (1410,1): error C2238: unexpected tokens before ";"
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSV C\14.29.30037\include\random (1863.5): error C2760: syntax error: unexpected token "id"; "expression" is required
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\random (1885): message: a reference to an instance of the class function template "std :: uniform_int_distribution <_Ty> "
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\random (1863.5): error C2187: syntax error: unexpected element "id" here
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\random (1863.5): error C2062: "unsigned int" type is not required
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\random (1863,1): error C2238: unexpected tokens before ";"
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\random (2062.5): error C2760: syntax error: unexpected token "id"; "expression" is required
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\random (2164): message: a reference to an instance of the class function template "std :: geometric_distribution <_Ty> "
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\random (2062.5): error C2187: syntax error: unexpected element "id" here
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\random (2062.5): error C2062: "unsigned int" type is not required
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\random (2062,1): error C2238: unexpected tokens before ";"
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\random (2222.5): error C2760: syntax error: unexpected token "id"; "expression" is required
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\random (2347): message: a reference to an instance of the class function template "std :: poisson_distribution <_Ty> "
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\random (2222.5): error C2187: syntax error: unexpected element "id" here
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\random (2222.5): error C2062: "unsigned int" type is not required
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\random (2222,1): error C2238: unexpected tokens before ";"
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\random (2379.5): error C2760: syntax error: unexpected token "id"; "expression" is required
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\random (2554): message: a reference to an instance of the class function template "std :: binomial_distribution <_Ty> "
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\random (2379.5): error C2187: syntax error: unexpected element "id" here
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\random (2379.5): error C2062: "unsigned int" type is not required
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\random (2379,1): error C2238: unexpected tokens before ";"
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\random (4272.5): error C2760: syntax error: unexpected token "id"; "expression" is required
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\random (4388): message: a reference to an instance of the class function template "std :: negative_binomial_distribution <_Ty> "
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\random (4272.5): error C2187: syntax error: unexpected element "id" here
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\random (4272.5): error C2062: "unsigned int" type is not required
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\random (4272,1): error C2238: unexpected tokens before ";"
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\random (4418.5): error C2760: syntax error: unexpected token "id"; "expression" is required
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\random (4587): message: running compiling an instance reference class function template "std :: discrete_distribution <_Ty>"
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\random (4418.5): error C2187: syntax error: unexpected element "id" here
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\random (4418.5): error C2062: "unsigned int" type is not required
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\random (4418,1): error C2238: unexpected tokens before ";"
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\random (4418.5): error C2059: syntax error :,
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\random (4418): error C2062: "unknown-type" is not required
1> Build of the project "test.vcxproj" completed with an error.
========== Build: success: 0, with errors: 1, no changes: 0, skipped: 0 ==========
```

FIXED.
"random" became changed somehow, its size was 172 053 bytes, when must be 172 041 bytes. Reinstalled VS and made a backup archive of these files.

Thank you for your help guys

Comment: You rebuild solutions / restart VS / restart Windows / repair VS. Usually one of those works. Though the project file could be corrupted also but unlikely.

Comment: Check your project setting for command line defines.

Comment: line 374 is the first use of the `_RNG_REQUIRE_UINTTYPE` macro, I'd guess it or one of the macros it uses has been corrupted or there's a conflicting definition from somewhere else, `random` should be `172,041` bytes. `Get-FileHash "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\random"` should return `7A8378B21B6DC5AE4573D49CA6277A5C6B87C34FD1DF5F4C481584CA4C086862`

Comment: My random file has different size and hash
And I created a brand new project, the problem wasn't solved. Also, I didn't change any VS settings for about a week. The problem just appeared for no noticeable reason
As I understood from the comments, I have to reinstall VS. Will try to find a better solution, but if I wont get lucky to find one, will reinstall it and tell if it worked.

Answer (score -4):

You may include only one header file in your code i.e. `#include<bits/stdc++.h>`
It will take care of all your header files.

Comment: Including ["bits/stdc++.h" is not encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h).

Comment: Yes, you are right but it can be very handy if you get stuck somewhere.